# Advice / Cure for boredom in Islam

Tags: work, health

I suffer from depression and have been on medication for many years which works and this may be a factor.

However I go through phases of being bored. Same routine, same daily predictable job, etc. Very predictable. Even in spare time I'm bored. I like to sleep.

You may say you should listen to the Qur'an. I do but as I don't know Arabic I don't get the full benefit.

Other things like TV, films and music are haraam by the majority of scholars so I can't entertain myself via them.

Is there any advice in Islam on this or any practical advice you may have please?

Comment: Subscribe to some Islamic channels (e.g [The Daily Reminder](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIuUOdkiW3uUD3ITS5PCK_A), [TheMercifulServant](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHGAqdQBKTVON_FUCIYCh3Q),[Islamic Guidance](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNDpwS2nEiGiJAW3Oe-3zBg),[Muslim Speakers](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCX4kkW2kc-x_3EbbkxhZZLw),[OnePath Network
](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQHRLH8RQIrdGWMhf5heWiA) at youtube and watch their videos to overcome your boredom.

Comment: There are stories about well-respected sahaba that did things exclusively for fun, islam does not expect you to immerse yourself in the religion around the clock. Get a hobby, explore different restaurants and food cultures with friends, join a sports club, relax/have intimacy with your wife, read books, play games. This doesn't qualify as an answer, but don't make your life needlessly stressful/joyless.

Comment: Agree with G Bach.  Also "by the majority of scholars", I think it is who we define scholar here and who not. But I don't agree that one can't live without TV and Music when there a so much you can do. There are plenty of stuff you could do which doesn't have to be religious stuff. (philosophically you might even call that things religious even though they tend not to be)